# Zend 2 Rotate logging

Tags: php, logging, zend-framework2

I use the Zend Log for logging information to my logfile. I am looking forward for a way to automatically write in monthly logfiles like logfile201601.log, logile201602.log etc.

Is there a way to to achieve that ? Any hints or a tutorial ? Didn't found anything like that on my current research.

My current configuration:

```
'factories' => array(
        'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter' => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory',
        'Zend\Log' => function ($sm) {
                $logger = new Zend\Log\Logger(array(
                    'writers' => array(
                        'stream' => array(
                            'name' => 'stream',
                            'options' => array(
                                'stream' => './data/log/logfile2016.log',
                                'formatter' => array(
                                    'name' => 'simple',
                                    'options' => array(
                                        'dateTimeFormat' => 'Y-m-d H:i:s'
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
                ));
                return $logger;
        },
);
```

Comment: Don't know if it could be useful, first thing that come to mind... did you try something like using `'./data/log/logfile2016'.date_create()->format('m').'.log'` as your stream?

Comment: Yeah your awnser is right :). Worked for me !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Zend will automatically create the log file, you can just dynamically create your log file with the `date()` function:

```
// ...
'stream' => './data/log/logfile'.date("Ym").'.log',
// ...
```

Note that the `log` directory must be writable.